# amazon s3 - playlist video with hide link & wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, playlist

I'm using Amazon s3 and I want to display playlist in my WordPress website, the special thing that the link of videos should be hiding, or encrypted does anyone have idea ?!

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin to generate secure URL for those videos.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/s3-secure-url/

Comment: The issue that the client want the url to be encrypted or hidden, not just to be accessible for few minutes.